# Discord Return Specified user's activity status

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

i'm trying to create a bot that checks the activity status of a server's users and returns them. i'm having trouble actually retrieveing the activity status from the users and i don't even know if it's possible.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token ='nah';
const PREFIX = '//';
function Statuscheck() {
    ///Code for retrieval of the status check would go here
    console.log('set');///So I know the timer works
}


client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot is running...');
})

client.on('ready', () =>{
    setInterval(Statuscheck, 10000)//runs the check funtion evrey 10s to keep up to date
})

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**, I do a **for loop through all guilds** on which the bot is on. In this loop I do another loop **through all guildMembers**. I push the status of every single [`guildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) in a **new Array** which I add in **an Object** at the end of the loop.
Maybe this sounds really complicated but it isn't very complicated if you understand **basics of Javascript**.

(I wasn't sure if you want the status of the user (*online/offline/dnd/idle*) or the game status. **If you want the game status**, change the line **`status.push(m.user.presence.status)`** to **`status.push(m.user.presence.game)`**)

**Try using the following code:**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'nah';
const PREFIX = '//';

async function statuscheck() {
    const statusArray = {};
    await client.guilds.array().forEach(async g => {
        const status = [];
        await g.members.array().forEach(m => {
            status.push(m.user.presence.status);
        });
        statusArray[g.id] = status;
    });
    console.log('set'); // /So I know the timer works
    return statusArray;
}


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is running...');
});

client.on('ready', async client => {
    setInterval(await statuscheck(client), 10000); // runs the check funtion evrey 10s to keep up to date
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Hi again. yes, I am trying to get the activity status (Online, Idle, and, offline) and this is definitely a big step in the right direction. when I ran your code I got This error [link](https://pastebin.com/zp7D3AJU). I'm gonna have a look into it but it's been a long while since I last coded. A previous similar question mentioned [link](https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/SERVERID/embed.json) which returns each user's basic info along with their activity status. I need to specify which users to monitor would it be possible to use this? if not I can work with what you've given me. :)

Comment: I am sorry that this issue happened, could you maybe tell my which line 26 is in your index.js so I know where I have to look for issues? :) Thanks! @Babbe

Comment: I've sorted the Callback error by changing `setInterval(await statuscheck(client), 10000);` to `setInterval(() => statuscheck(client), 10000);`. i've fixed the problem but i've got a bunch of other ones i have no idea how to fix so i'm gonna answer my question and open a new one to sort that out. ty <3

Comment: You‘re welcome! :) mind accepting my answer? @Babbe